# Do not hide keyboard after tapping on the "insert link" button

Tags: bug, android-app

In the process of post editing tapping on the "insert link" button hides keyboard. So if I decide to cancel it, I need to tap on the post body again to show keyboard. In this case last cursor position can be accidentally changed.

Better do not hide keyboard if it already opened when tapping on the "insert link" button.

- App Version: 1.0.89
- Device Manufacturer: LGE
- Device Model: LG-H860
- OS Version: 6.0.1 (1626721325f7f)